# Shut down application remotely before database refresh

Tags: sql-server, powershell, wmi

In our ERP application we refresh a Test Instance Database from Production daily, typically shutting down the front end application first.  We currently use psexec issued from the Database Server to look after the remote call and pass a few commands to shutdown the application before the database refresh commences.

As we are moving to a network which doesn't support running psexec, I was looking for ideas or help either using WMI or Powershell to add to the SQL Refresh job to shut down the application remotely.

Typically once we have gained cmd shell access on the remote Server we issue:

```
SET APPSERVER=HCM83CPY
SET DATABASE=HR83CPY
echo Shutting down %DATABASE% Application Server...
echo.
ECHO Shutting down Application Server
d:
CHDIR D:\psoft\HR\%APPSERVER%\appserv
psadmin -c shutdown! -d %DATABASE%
```

Appreciate replies

Answer (score 0):

WMI can be a pain to configure, especially if you're on a secure network.  Here's [some guidance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you want to go down that route.

You didn't say what OS's you have at each end.  If you're on 2008 R2 or later, you already have PowerShell 2.0.  If you can install 3.0 or 4.0, you'll get a better experience (easier to [set up remoting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849694.aspx), auto-loading of modules, for example).  As long as you're on PowerShell 2.0, you should take a look at PowerShell remoting.  Fire up powershell and run:

```
help about_remoting
```

From there, you'll be lead to:

- about_PSSessions
- about_Remote_Disconnected_Sessions
- about_Remote_Requirements
- about_Remote_FAQ
- about_Remote_TroubleShooting
- about_Remote_Variables

There's quite a bit of reading to do and I can't possibly do it justice here but to whet your appetite, once remoting is configured, you can issue this on the source machine:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server1 -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem C:\ }
```

to get the contents of server1's C:.  You're not limited to running PowerShell commands.  For example,

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server1 -ScriptBlock { ipconfig /all }
```

will bring back the detailed ipconfig from server1.  You can establish sessions and run multiple commands using variables (local and remote).  You can, if you want, also use WMI but using the new CIM cmdlets which run over WinRM - the same technology used by PowerShell remoting - rather than evil DCOM.  Try `Get-Command *cim*` to get a list and then use 'help' to get more info.

Comment: Thanks for this, good feedback!  I'm going to spend time first working with Powershell and see where it takes me.